# Trying to read all Documents through all indexes through OpenSearch +LlamaIndex: ElasticsearchReader(endpoint, idx). Cant use "*" or "_all" in idx

Tags: opensearch

Trying to read all  Documents through all indexes through OpenSearch: ElasticsearchReader(endpoint, idx). Cant use "*" or "_all" in idx.

Error:  raise mapped_exc(message) from exc httpx.ReadTimeout: timed out

Text_field="Title" // There are only 2 indices in OpenSearch having one document in each index. Title is    common field in both Documents.
rdr = ElasticsearchReader(endpoint, idx)
docs = rdr.load_data(text_field,{  "query": { "match_all": {} }}   )

Comment: Didn't understand why you can't use "** or "_all" but if you can't specify any index name, the `_search` API will hit all indices by default. Example: `GET _search`